# Show button on ng-grid hover

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Is there any way of showing a button on row hover in ng-grid (something like http://jsfiddle.net/andrewboni/fnAwN/light/)?

I'm constantly running in issues with the scope (I think).

I've a row template:

```
rowTemplate: '<div ng-mouseover="grid.appScope.showButton()" ng-mouseout="grid.appScope.hideButton()">
<div ng-repeat="col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell" ui-grid-cell>
</div>
</div>',
```

and a cell template with a button in it:

```
cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents button-cell">
<button ng-click="grid.appScope.removeRow(row)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right" ng-show="grid.appScope.button">
delete
</button>
</div>'
```

However, when I hover a row a button turns up not just in the hovered row, but in every row.

Full code: http://plnkr.co/edit/UV9R4GbaREmchXKpSjfx?p=preview

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use css hover selector for this case instead of "ng-show", "ng-mouseover", "ng-mouseout", like this:

**HTML Template**

```
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents button-cell">
<button ng-click="grid.appScope.removeRow(row)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right my-button">delete</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .my-button {
   display: none;
 }
.ui-grid-row:hover .my-button {
  display: block;
}
```

Link demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/ixbxp1gGlDD6I5hHYhHS?p=preview